# how to share variables between subset of notebooks

Tags: kernel, system

I have some notebooks belonging to a project.  I want them to share definitions with each other, but not with other notebooks.

Here is one approach that I thought would accomplish this: go to `Evaluation > Kernel Configuration Options` and add a new kernel, say `mykernel`.  Then in each project notebook execute `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator -> "mykernel"]` to reset the kernel for that notebook.

To my surprise, symbol definitions appear to be shared across kernels.  That is, if I have a non-project notebook running (`Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel` is `local`), it still sees all the defintions in the project notebooks.

I seem to have misunderstood what it means to assign a new kernel, which I though was equivalent to say "run in a separate process".  I did not find the documentation helpful in understanding what is going on here.  How can I get what I want?

**Edit:**

I had closed and restarted Mma once to check on this behavior, and I still got the reported behavior.  After Kuba's comments I did so again (as part of a more extensive experiment), and now I cannot replicate the reported behavior.  I will edit this question again if I see it again (and would appreciate any confirming reports, especially if the cause is discovered).

**Edit 2:**

Motivation for use of separate kernel: privacy.  (I don't want to worry about name clashes.)

Why not use contexts via `Begin`?  As far as I can tell, `Begin` is almost completely unsafe for this purpose.  Example:

```
ClearAll[f, x]
Begin["MyContext`"]
f[x_] := x^2 + 1
End[]
?? f
```

We find the definition apparently inside the block is in fact global (because the symbol `f` already existed at the global level).

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. What is `Options[$FrontEnd, Evaluator]`?

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896011/mathematica-separating-notebooks

Comment: @Kuba  Interesting.  Although the project notebooks show `Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel` is `mykernel`, I see that `Options[$FrontEnd, Evaluator]` produces {Evaluator -> "Local"}.  How to reconcile?  (Mma 10.2 on Win 7)

Comment: @Kuba So I think you are saying that my expectation was reasonable and what I am experiencing is surprising.

Comment: @Alan Indeed :)

Comment: I think `TaggingRules` is probably the easiest way to set this up. Notebooks outside of the project could still access the rules of course but it is not clear from the description of the problem whether those other notebooks need to be excluded for convenience or privacy or some other reason.

Comment: The problem of your `f` definition is that ``Global`f`` was created when the `Clear` command was read.

Comment: @Kuba  Yes, that is why I included it.  My point: was that use of `Begin` blocks does not give the needed privacy.

Answer (score 2):

The described method with another Kernel works well for me. But here's another way, set this options for notebook you want to "shield":

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 {CellProlog :> BeginPackage["c1`"], 
  CellEpilog :> (EndPackage[]; $ContextPath =.)}
 ]
```

or simply:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  CellContext -> "test`"
]
```

Comment: Maybe just drop `c1` from $ContexPath instead of reseting it, your call.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of each notebook for a particular project, say ProjectNexus add the following `` Begin["ProjectNexus`"] `` . Make sure all the notebooks corresponding to the same project are in the same kernel.

Comment: As far as I know, all global symbols that reappear inside a `Begin` block are treated as global rather than context specific.  See my edit.